# sed: can't read No such file or directory

Tags: sed

```
sed -i -e "s@^ filename:.*.infos.log@ filename:${log_dir}/infos.log@" ${default_config_dir}/logging.conf
```

I tried to execute the above command but it always tells me that

```
sed: can't read /logging.conf: No such file or directory
```

even though there is a file in that location with that name.

Answer (score 1):

The leading slash in your message is a clear indication that the variable `${default_config_dir}` is either unset or empty.